# how to use actionStatus for picklist in vf page..?

Tags: visualforce, community, picklist, actionstatus

I have two picklist. One picklist have country values and one picklist have state values. I am giving those values through controller. Based on country name state piclist changed. It's taking taking some time to load state picklist. Meanwhile i need to show some text or image using actionStatus. Can anyone tell me how to use actionStatus for picklist.

Comment: Any specific reason not to use the dependent picklist feature in salesforce?

Comment: It is custom page.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working example of **actionStatus**. I have used 5000ms delay to show the message. Hope this will help.

**VF Page**

```
<apex:page controller="loadingSpinnerCtrl">
    <apex:form id="form">
        <apex:selectList id="selected_list" value="{!dropdown1}" required="false" size="1">
            <apex:selectOption itemvalue="None" itemLabel="--None--"/>
            <apex:selectOption itemvalue="1" itemLabel="First"/>
            <apex:selectOption itemvalue="2" itemLabel="Second"/>
            <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" reRender="form" action="{!spin}" status="status"/>
        </apex:selectList>
        <apex:actionStatus id="status">
            <apex:facet name="start">
                <div>Loading Please wait........</div>
            </apex:facet>
        </apex:actionStatus>
        <apex:selectList id="dropdown2"  required="false" size="1">
            <apex:selectOption itemvalue="None" itemLabel="--None--"/>
            <apex:selectOptions value="{!items}" />
        </apex:selectList>        
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

**Controller**

```
public class loadingSpinnerCtrl {
    public String dropdown1{get; set;}
    public List<SelectOption> options;
    public void spin() {
        if(dropdown1 == '1'){
            options = new List<SelectOption>();
            options.add(new SelectOption('1','Value 1'));
            options.add(new SelectOption('2','Value 2'));
            options.add(new SelectOption('3','Value 3'));

        }else if(dropdown1 == '2'){
            options = new List<SelectOption>();
            options.add(new SelectOption('1','Case 1'));
            options.add(new SelectOption('2','case 2'));
            options.add(new SelectOption('3','case 3'));

        }    
        long now = datetime.now().gettime();
        while(datetime.now().gettime()-now<5000); // Busy loop for 5000 ms
    }
    public List<SelectOption> getItems() {
        return options;
    }    
}
```